# how can i display just a calendar on the screen

Tags: android

i have been browsing for the last 4 hours and found out that i have to create a calendarview in my xml and instantiate it in my java file. but i can't really understadn how to display the actual calendar itself on the screen.

my xml file

```
  <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

java file

```
 package org.example.calender;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CalenderActivity extends Activity {
    Calendar calender;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        calender = (Calendar)findViewById(R.id.calen);
    }
}
```

Additionally, it s giving error on "CALEN" however my id of calendarview is "CALEN" as well..

any help, tips and guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply try this code:::

```
package org.example.calender;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CalenderActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CalenderView(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man that worked for me aalthough it gave a error, "could not find apk" but i reasearched for the solution and solved it.. BUT I STILL NOT SHOWING THE CALENDAR ONT HE SCREEN :(...

Comment: becasue my code had two errors and yet, just one error is solved which was coming on the work "calen", but the problem is still persisting..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as changing:

```
calender = (Calendar)findViewById(R.id.calen);
```

to:

```
CalendarView calender = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calen);
```

Comment: Have you updated your import files? An Android CalendarView comes from `android.widget.CalendarView` not `java.util.Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 package org.example.calender;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CalenderActivity extends Activity {
    CalendarView calender;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        calender = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calen);
    }
}
```